# How to download .zip file from web URL using Perl Script?

Tags: perl, url, download

I want to download a .zip file which is available at URL http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/cmbhav.htm by clicking on "Download file in csv format".

If right click on "Download file in csv format" and select copy link location then the URL pattern will be like
http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2012/MAR/cm23MAR2012bhav.csv.zip.

I want to write a Perl Script that will download the .zip file from the URL.

The below code is not working

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2012/MAR' ;
my $file = 'cm23MAR2012bhav.csv.zip'    ;
getstore($url, $file) ;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to change the user agent and still want to use [LWP::Simple](https://www.metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple), you can use the `$ua` export:

```
use File::Basename;
use LWP::Simple qw($ua getstore);
use URI;

my $url = URI->new( 'http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2012/MAR/cm23MAR2012bhav.csv.zip' );

$ua->default_headers( HTTP::Headers->new(
    Accept => '*/*', 
    )
    );

$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.54.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.4 Safari/534.54.16");

my $rc = getstore( $url, basename( $url->path ) );
say "Result is $rc";
```

It turns out the combination of a user agent string and the Accept header will do it. Typically these problems come down to making your LWP request look just like the request that your browser would send. I use [HTTPScoop](http://tuffcode.com/) to watch the browser transactions, but there are plenty of programs that will do the same thing for you.

If things get even this complex, though, I favor [Mojo::UserAgent](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent). It's a bit easier to play with the transaction:

```
use File::Basename;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use URI;

my $url = URI->new( 'http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2012/MAR/cm23MAR2012bhav.csv.zip' );
my $file = basename( $url->path );
printf "URL: %s\nFile: %s\n", $url, $file;

my $response = Mojo::UserAgent->new->name(
    '"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.54.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.4 Safari/534.54.16"'
    )->get( $url->as_string, { Accept => '*/*' } )->res;

open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Could not open [$file]: $!";
print $fh $response->body;
printf "Status: %d\n", $response->code;
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me since I've tried in time. If you couldn't, how did you know it works?? I wonder... I've taken the User Agent string from http://www.user-agents.org/ ... I would -1 the answer for this, if I'd be silly as many users on Q/A sites (often this one is no exception). _Moreover_ that wouldn't get the zip, but the page containing the link to the zip. OP's error, which I silently fixed in my "-1" answer. Though the OP has to do the little effort of redirecting the output or changin a bit the code to save the file as he wanted

Comment: How do I know that I can change the user agent? I do this quite a bit. I did look at the HTTP request and response directly too. I have no idea what you're trying to say with the rest of your comment.

Comment: No, how do you know it would fix the problem! (It happened to me that simply changing the User-Agent was not enough). It was a point about "logical processes" of judgment, that I often do not get.

Comment: I think you missed the part in my first version where I said I couldn't tell if it solved the problem. When I tried this morning, I could fetch the resource so I modified my answer. However, my particular change to the user-agent is unimportant. It's that you can affect the user-agent that's the important thing.

Comment: Yes I missed that part, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
       print getstore($url, $file);
```

you see you get 403 as error (forbidden).

**ADD**

experimenting with curl, it seems they do a check on the user-agent, so you can't use LWP::Simple since you have to set an user agent as real browsers do.

**ADD2**

the following works

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
my $url = 'http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2012/MAR/cm23MAR2012bhav.csv.zip';
#my $file = 'cm23MAR2012bhav.csv.zip';
#my $url = 'http://localhost:11000';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (FM Scene 4.6.1)");
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
$req->header(Accept => "*/*");
# $req->remove_header('Connection');  # does not work
# $req->remove_header('TE');          # does not work
my $res = $ua->request($req);
if ($res->is_success)
{
    print $res->content;
}
else
{
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
}
```

Headers TE and Connection are not removed by the lines remove_header, since they are inserted at the protocol level so that removing them is a different procedure (that I don't know).

Anyway this is enough to make it work.

(**edit** I had a final space in the UserAgent string, which caused LWP to add `libwww-perl` and this was the reason why the server gave 403)

**important note**

you had to redirect output, or change a bit the code to save the content to a file. Note also that to download the zip, you had to feed the correct URL for it and not the URL of the page containing the link to the zip.

Comment: You can change the user agent that LWP::Simple uses.

Comment: I've always used ::Simple in the simplest way and never checked if and what can be customised! Good to know, thanks.

Comment: and again I wonder why someone put -1 on a correct answer that also gives a correct solution. There's an easiest way still using ::Simple? No matter, the answer is still correct and _works_. Sometimes I forget it could be time spent so badly - even if few minutes. The extra lines in the code was just (personal) attempt to make LWP send a request identical to cURL.

Comment: Why would you think time is spent badly because someone down votes an answer you like? The questioner still gets your answer, you figured something out, and it's still available to the world. None of those are negated by a downvote. You just need up votes.

Comment: No it's a philosophical (so to say) matter. It's not exactly about down/up voting, but it's about the process and judgment people have to decide up/down/no voting (and partly about how this can influence judgment of less knowledged people who have less "tools" to judge an answer). The argument is broad and totally OT, I just like to be polemical sometimes!